# Yellow circle around cursor in Java

Tags: java, cursor, geometry, marker

I'm trying to figure out how to make a yellow circle around the cursor in Java. The thing is that we've got a screen-recorder that (obviously) records the screen. Using the keywords "Yellow circle around cursor in Java" on Google only takes me to how to add a yellow circle around the cursor on a MAC, on WM and other applications, but not how to do it in Java on a users computer when the application starts.

How can I do it without using existing images? Drawing a simple yellow circle with some opacity would be the easiest thing to do, making it follow the mouse on the screen. And also, if it is possible to make it disappear and reappear when the user clicks a mouse-button, that'd be awesome.

Comment: Have you heard about `Swings`?

Comment: @michael667 Well, since I can't find anything other than how to change the actual cursor it's quite hard to actually try doing something. I haven't found any real examples or theories on how to do it. And my JAVA-knowledge isn't that advanced either. I develop websites usually.

Comment: @Subs If you mean Swing, then yes, even though I'm not sure how that would help me figure out what class to use to make the cursor more visible. The thing is the java swing library is kind of huge. I mean, it's pretty easy to find the mouse-listeners.. But it's harder to figure out how to make a circle around the mouse.

Comment: @NanashiDri, if you know then you should have figured out that you can put a transparent panel as the top layer and draw a circle from the mouse pointer position and when you click (`mousePressed`) - hide the transparent panel so that now your back (main) panel takes your `mousereleased` event.

Comment: @Sub, That's true, though, I'm still not sure how to make that panel always follow the mouse. Also, I'm not sure if it could work like in JavaScript, that you take a mouseMove event and change the x|y position of that panel, get the x|y coordinates of the mouse and make the panels center x|y position stick to the mouse x|y position. If that works, would it be too demanding on the computer using the application, or wouldn't the user using the application notice any delays? This is all theories, and even if I know how to do it in theory, I don't have the slightest idea of how to make it in code.

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Comment: Yeah, check the answer below. That was the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not possible to add a circle around the existing mouse pointer. You can only set the mouse pointer to a complete image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid it's not the solution. If I'd found an answer while searching, I wouldn't have asked here. The problem is that I don't want to change the mouse cursor completely. I just want to create a yellow circle around it. And my question was if that's possible without using images.

Comment: It's not possible to add a circle around the existing mouse pointer. You can only set the mouse pointer to a complete image.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer. I'll mark your answer as the answer for this question since I don't think it's possible to mark comments as accepted answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this by attaching a MouseMotionListener to your component, but it will take a little work to get it working exactly how you want it.

I would start from something like this:

```
private static final double RADIUS    = 15.0;
private static final double DIAMETER  = 2.0 * RADIUS;
private static final Color  XOR_COLOR = Color.yellow;

private static Shape m_circle = null;

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
    Graphics2D g2     = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
    Point      p      = e.getPoint();
    Shape      circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(p.getX() - RADIUS, p.getY() - RADIUS, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);

    clearCircle(g2);

    g2.setXORMode(XOR_COLOR);
    g2.draw(circle);
    g2.setPaintMode();

    m_circle = circle;
}

private void clearCircle(Graphics2D g2)
{
    if (m_circle != null)
    {
        g2.setXORMode(XOR_COLOR);
        g2.draw(m_circle);
        g2.setPaintMode();

        m_circle = null;
    }
}
```

It will also be necessary to make sure that the old circle is cleared on the mouseExited event which you can listen for by adding a MouseListener. This also has the mousePressed/mouseReleased/mouseClicked events that you need for making it disappear/reappear on a user's mouse click.

Using XOR is convenient because it is very easy to restore the screen by repainting the same shape with the same color and style but it isn't quite what you asked for. It is possible to repair the screen by capturing an image of the area that you are about to draw the circle into. The circle can be removed from the screen by repainting the damaged area before painting a circle in a new position.

Comment: `getGraphics() ` where does it come from ?

Comment: can you post a complete working example ? I tried something but it didn't worked out.

Comment: getGraphics() originally comes from java.awt.Component but this code needs a subclass that returns a Graphics2D instance, such as javax.swing.JComponent

Comment: The code in my answer is just the implementation of mouseMoved(...) for a class implementing MouseMotionListener. If you need a complete working example Java application, this Java tutorial provides a good starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html - you should be able to replace the stub implementation of mouseMoved with my code.